# How to deselect a nested JSON object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Currently my code is `console.log("body:", body.readResults)`. But I do not want the value `t` and `r`. How to deselect them and get the rest?

```
"readResults": [
   {
       "id": "Channel1.Device1.Coil",
       "s": true,
       "r": "",
       "v": true,
       "t": 1553586722927
    }
]
```

Comment: Format your code, take the [tour], and then reformulate your question so that it is understandable.

Comment: what what will be there instead of `t` & `r`c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Remove attribute for all objects in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133635/javascript-remove-attribute-for-all-objects-in-array) and [Remove specific properties from Array objects in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44888732)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily:

```
function cleanMyResult(result) {
    const cleanResult = Object.assign({}, result); // this will preserve your original object, but it costs some performance
    delete cleanResult.t;
    delete cleanResult.r;
    return cleanResult;
}

const cleanedResults = body.readResults.map(cleanMyResult);
console.log(cleanedResults);
```

Please check also a lot of already good answers available on SO:

- [Filter object properties by key in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750705/filter-object-properties-by-key-in-es6)
- [Simplest way to copy JS object and filter out certain properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39972428/simplest-way-to-copy-js-object-and-filter-out-certain-properties)
- [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object?rq=1)

Comment: @YaHtet good! So please accept my answer using the checkmark, so others will be able to understand quickly that your question was solved.